# Possible reasons for docker swarm loosing ingress load balancing after patching of underlying VM and upgrade of docker version

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, containers, docker-swarm, rhel8

We have a set of 3 managers and 3 workers in a docker swarm cluster (community edition) running on RHEL 8.1 in a DMZ. We have a similar like to like set up in a non prod environment where we don't have issues when we patch the underlying VMs to latest RHEL 8.x versions including the docker version upgrade to the latest versions.

But any time we try patching the production cluster VMs, even though the swarm on the surface comes back up fine and we see all the services and tasks running, but for some weird reason the docker swarm looses the docker ingress load balancing capability. We have tried upgrading several different ways and many times, but every time we end up with same result and we have had to revert.

Can any one please shed some light into where to look and why this could be happening ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
ethtool -K <interface> tx off
```

Fixed it for us, see: [Docker Swarm Overlay Network ICMP Works, But Not Anything Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251422/docker-swarm-overlay-network-icmp-works-but-not-anything-else)